# application + folder desktop shortcuts

Tags: 18.04, shortcuts

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04. How can I add shortcuts to my desktop like in Windows? I'd like to make a shortcut for e.g. the Spotify application (so not a native ubuntu app), and I want to make shortcuts for folders.

Answer (score 0):

It is not that obvious in Ubuntu because there is a tendency to move away from icons on the desktop. Gnome Shell, on which Ubuntu is based, even does not support icons on the desktop anymore. Ubuntu re-introduced icons on the desktop in Ubuntu 19.10 by using a Gnome Shell extension. In Ubuntu 18.04, desktop icons are still provided by the file manager. Specially for this, they included an version of Files that is older than that belonging to the version of Gnome Shell.

Still, it can be done. (*instructions adapted for Ubuntu 19.10 in italics*)

1. Find the corresponding launcher file on your system. In "Files", move to "Other Locations" in the side bar, then in the folder pane, go to "Computer", then in "usr", then "share", "applications". This contains the vast majority of launchers for applications installed on your system. Find the launcher you want, and copy it.
2. In Ubuntu 18.04, you can drag that file to your desktop. *Ubuntu 19.10 users should copy the file to the "Desktop" folder in their home folder using the file manager.*
3. The launcher looks weird, but that will be fixed in a moment. In Ubuntu 18.04, double-click the launcher. You will get a warning dialog:

[image]

4. Select "Trust and Launch". Now, the launcher will be turned into a normal, working launcher with the correct icon. *Ubuntu 19.10 users should right-click the launcher on the desktop and then select "Allow launching".*

Comment: There is no "share" in my "Computer" folder :(

Comment: It is /usr/share/applications. I have corrected this.